# Category Icon Image not being shown in Magento 2, Porto theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, porto-theme, porto

I am new on magento2, working to develop multiple stores. Just got stuck with following problem since last many hours. Any positive response is much appreciated

I have created 2 websites, each with one store, and each store with one store view.
[image]

Now, in the PortoStoreView, I am trying to modify the nav menu, by adding category icon. So, from the admin panel, under Category section, I have created new category and set its icon. But it is not displaying the image

[image]

So, I inspect it and found that, it is due to invalid URL of the image. By default image is being stored in following folder: store\pub\media\catalog\category

But it is accessing following path(as can be seen in inspect) to display image.
[image]

At other places for example product page it is working fine, it is displaying the images. But just on the navbar, it is functioning strange.

Additional Info: In my root folder, I have created a folder PortoStore and added index.html and .htaccess files in it. If you need any other information, please ask.

Comment: If you observe the image `src` path there are 2 `/` slashes is there. Remove the `/` where you appending before `pub`.

Comment: @Bojjaiah I am not manually setting the path, I am setting category icon using admin panel. And removing / doesn't make any difference. If we remove PortoStore/ then it shows the image.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338591/single-and-double-backslash-in-path